# Magento 2 Constructor returns Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError. How to resolve?

Tags: magento2, cart, controllers, redirect, fatal-error

```
<?php

namespace Module\Name\Controller\Index;

class Myclass extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{


protected $formKey;   
protected $cart;
protected $product;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
array $data = []) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;      
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
 { 
  $productId =481;
  $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $productId, //product Id
                'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
            );              
    //Load the product based on productID   
    $_product = $this->product->load($productId);       
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
 }


}
```

Comment: Please, post your error here.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Rk\Wallet\Controller\Index\Wallet::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory given, called in /home/rkhomeappliances/public_html/test/var/generation/Rk/Wallet/Controller/Index/Wallet/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /home/rkhomeappliances/public_html/test/app/code/Rk/Wallet/Controller/Index/Wallet.php:18 Stack trace:

Comment: #0 /home/rkhomeappliances/public_html/test/var/generation/Rk/Wallet/Controller/Index/Wallet/Interceptor.php(14): Rk\Wallet\Controller\Index\Wallet->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\Interceptor))

Comment: #1 /home/rkhomeappliances/public_html/test/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Rk\Wallet\Controller\Index\Wallet\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Co in /home/rkhomeappliances/public_html/test/app/code/Rk/Wallet/Controller/Index/Wallet.php on line 18

Comment: These errors I get..Errors are too long

Comment: Remove generation folder.

Comment: sure?Any issue will I get If I remove It?

Comment: What is the use of generation folder?

Comment: What's your Magento version?

Comment: Magento 2.1. Thaks A lot. It worked fine

Comment: In my code I added product That should add in cart when this controller is called. But It shows this error ""We can't find the product." But product Id of 481 is in my db.